# xpath for svg ,cannot locate based on path attribute

Tags: python, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to locate icon based on SVG. Xpath is not working. Only way to distinguish both icon is using this attribute , but that is not working.

```
<path d="M8 5v14l11-7z"
```

I have tried:

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path' and @d="M8 5v14l11-7z"]
```

No luck

```
<div class="page-details-box-links ng-scope" style="">
            <button class="icon-style >
                <div c style="">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="">
                        <path d="M8 5v14l11-7z" style=""></path>
                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" style=""></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div  style="">Run job</div>
            </button>
            <button style="">
                <div  style="">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="">
                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" style=""></path>
                        <path d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98s-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.12-.22-.39-.3-.61-.22l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65C14.46 2.18 14.25 2 14 2h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.23-.09-.49 0-.61.22l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98s.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.12.22.39.3.61.22l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.23.09.49 0 .61-.22l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zM12 15.5c-1.93 0-3.5-1.57-3.5-3.5s1.57-3.5 3.5-3.5 3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5-1.57 3.5-3.5 3.5z" style=""></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="cv-material-button-tooltip" style="">Edit</div>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your XPath is OK, but check whether required icon located inside `iframe` or it's generated dynamically

Comment: his xpath throws an exception cascade in selenium

Answer (score 1):

try with this xpath :

```
//button[contains(@class,'con-styl')]//*[name()='svg']/*[1]
```

Comment: it  could not detect path  tag

Answer (score 0):

To locate the *icon* based on *SVG* you can use the following *XPath*:

```
//div[@class='page-details-box-links ng-scope']/button[@class='icon-style']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and @d='M8 5v14l11-7z']
```

**Note**: The element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce a waiter through *WebDriverWait*

Comment: This did not work. It works till SVG but not going further to path and @d

Comment: @karthikloganathan My bad. Try out the updated answer and let me know the status.